# Django serializers vs values method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

What is the difference in using Model_Name.Objects.values().get() and serializers to get the data not in the form of model objects?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, whereas the Model.values().get() method will convert your entire model and all attribute fields to a dict, with a custom Serializer you can specify which attributes you want to include and which you don't.

## User model with .values().get()

```
x = User.objects.values().get(id=1)

print(x)

#{'id': 1,
 #'password': #'fdwfekwjgwlgkkk4j2oi4t243t4=',
 #'last_login': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 23, 17, 19, 28, 709800, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 #'is_superuser': True,
 #'username': 'weir.b',
 #'first_name': 'Bob',
 #'last_name': 'Weir',
 #'email': 'weir.bob@gd.com',
 #'is_staff': True,
 #'is_active': True,
 #'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 15, 2, 20, 618498, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 #'department': 'asdfsdf'}
```

## Compare to serializer output

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

s = UserSerializer(x)
print(s.data)

#{'username': 'weir.b', 'department': 'asdfsdf'}
```

Serializers are for exposing information about a model to an api client whereas the Model objects are a true representation of the data in the database. With a serializer you can also override and add custom methods e.g. validate().

Answer (score 0):

Serializer is used for multiple purposes. For every request method, this has different purpose.

1. For GET, it will give you data in representable form
2. For PUT/POST/PATCH, it will be used to validate data and saving after validation and doing any post saving business logic.

If your API only have GET method, they you can use `.values` method. Otherwise it is better to use serializer. But serializer will give you more control over your response. Like if you want to add some fields from other models or you want to rename some field in your response, it will be a lot easy in serializer.